# Axios sends GET and POST requests to localhost instead of the URL on heroku

Tags: spring-boot, vuex, heroku-postgres, nuxt.js

Axios sends GET and POST requests to localhost instead of the URL on heroku.
I am running a spring boot application on heroku and nuxt application on heroku.I want to change the baseUrl from http://localhost:8080 to https://spring-boota.herokuapp.com but this doesn't work.

store/index.js

```
 export const state = () => ({
    // Server - Back End Base Url
    baseUrl:'https://localhost:8080',
    prwtokolaUrl: 'v1/prwtokola',
    deigmataUrl: 'v1/deigmata',
    picturesUrl: 'v1/pictures',
    filesUrl: 'v1/files',
    deigmaThhlastikwnUrl: 'v1/deigmaThhlastikwn',
    thhlastikaCtEidosUrl: 'v1/ctThhlastikaEidh',
    thhlastikaCtPressThreatsUrl: 'v1/ctThhlastikaPressThreats',
    thhlastikaXEidhUrl: 'v1/deigmaThhlastikwnXEidh',
    thhlastikaXPressThreatsUrl: 'v1/deigmaThhlastikwnXPressThreats',
})

export const getters = {
    // Prwtokola
    getPrwtokolaAddUrl: state => {
        return state.baseUrl + state.prwtokolaUrl
    },
    getPrwtokolaAddFromExcelUrl: state => {
        return state.baseUrl + state.prwtokolaUrl + '/addPrwtokolaFromExcel'
    },
    getPrwtokolaSearchUrl: state => {
        return state.baseUrl + state.prwtokolaUrl + '/getAllByPaging'
    },
    getPrwtokolaByIdUrl: state => {
        return state.baseUrl + state.prwtokolaUrl + '/'
    },
    getPrwtokolaDistinctUrl: state => {
        return state.baseUrl + state.prwtokolaUrl + '/getDistinctIds'
    },

    // Deigmata
    getDeigmataSearchUrl: state => {
        return state.baseUrl + state.deigmataUrl + '/getAllByPaging'
    },
    getDeigmataByIdUrl: state => {
        return state.baseUrl + state.deigmataUrl + '/'
    },
    getDeigmataDynamicSearchUrl: state => {
        return state.baseUrl + state.deigmataUrl + '/search'
    },
    getDeigmataDynamicDownloadUrl: state => {
        return state.baseUrl + state.deigmataUrl + '/downloadExcel'
    },
    getDeigmataAutocompletes: state => {
        return state.baseUrl + state.deigmataUrl + '/getAutocompletes'
    },

    // Deigma Thhlastikwn
    getDeigmaThhlastikwnAddUrl: state => {
        return state.baseUrl + state.deigmaThhlastikwnUrl
    },
    getDeigmaThhlastikwnAddFromExcelUrl: state => {
        return state.baseUrl + state.deigmaThhlastikwnUrl + '/addDeigmaThhlastikwnFromExcel'
    },
    getDeigmaThhlastikwnSearchUrl: state => {
        return state.baseUrl + state.deigmaThhlastikwnUrl + '/getAllByPaging'
    },
    getDeigmaThhlastikwnByIdUrl: state => {
        return state.baseUrl + state.deigmaThhlastikwnUrl + '/'
    },
    getDeigmaThhlastikwnAutocompletesUrl: state => {
        return state.baseUrl + state.deigmaThhlastikwnUrl + '/getAutocompletes'
    },
    getDeigmaThhlastikwnMapMarkersUrl: state => {
        return state.baseUrl + state.deigmaThhlastikwnUrl + '/getAllGeoLocations'
    },
    getDeigmaThhlastikwnDynamicSearchUrl: state => {
        return state.baseUrl + state.deigmaThhlastikwnUrl + '/search'
    },
    getDeigmaThhlastikwnDynamicDownloadUrl: state => {
        return state.baseUrl + state.deigmaThhlastikwnUrl + '/downloadExcel'
    },
    getDeigmaThhlastikwnAutocompletes: state => {
        return state.baseUrl + state.deigmaThhlastikwnUrl + '/getAutocompletes'
    },

    // Pictures
    getPictureByIdUrl: state => {
        return state.baseUrl + state.picturesUrl + '/'
    },
    getPicturesByDeigmaThhlastikwnIdIs: state => {
        return state.baseUrl + state.picturesUrl + '/getPicturesByDeigmaThhlastikwnIs/'
    },
    getPicturesSearchUrl: state => {
        return state.baseUrl + state.picturesUrl + '/getAllByPaging/'
    },

    // Files
    getFileByIdUrl: state => {
        return state.baseUrl + state.filesUrl + '/'
    },
    getFilesByDeigmaThhlastikwnIdIs: state => {
        return state.baseUrl + state.filesUrl + '/getFilesByDeigmaThhlastikwnIs/'
    },
    getFilesSearchUrl: state => {
        return state.baseUrl + state.filesUrl + '/getAllByPaging/'
    },

    // Ct Eidh
    getThhlastikaCtEidosAddUrl: state => {
        return state.baseUrl + state.thhlastikaCtEidosUrl
    },
    getThhlastikaCtEidosAddFromExcelUrl: state => {
        return state.baseUrl + state.thhlastikaCtEidosUrl + '/addEidhFromExcel'
    },
    getThhlastikaCtEidosSearchUrl: state => {
        return state.baseUrl + state.thhlastikaCtEidosUrl + '/getAllByPaging'
    },
    getThhlastikaCtEidosByIdUrl: state => {
        return state.baseUrl + state.thhlastikaCtEidosUrl + '/'
    },
    getThhlastikaCtEidosDistinctUrl: state => {
        return state.baseUrl + state.thhlastikaCtEidosUrl + '/getAllEidh'
    },
    getCtEidhDynamicSearchUrl: state => {
        return state.baseUrl + state.thhlastikaCtEidosUrl + '/search'
    },
    getCtEidhDynamicDownloadUrl: state => {
        return state.baseUrl + state.thhlastikaCtEidosUrl + '/downloadExcel'
    },

    // Ct PressThreats
    getThhlastikaCtPressThreatsAddUrl: state => {
        return state.baseUrl + state.thhlastikaCtPressThreatsUrl
    },
    getThhlastikaCtPressThreatsAddFromExcelUrl: state => {
        return state.baseUrl + state.thhlastikaCtPressThreatsUrl + '/addPressThreatsFromExcel'
    },
    getThhlastikaCtPressThreatsSearchUrl: state => {
        return state.baseUrl + state.thhlastikaCtPressThreatsUrl + '/getAllByPaging'
    },
    getThhlastikaCtPressThreatsByIdUrl: state => {
        return state.baseUrl + state.thhlastikaCtPressThreatsUrl + '/'
    },
    getThhlastikaCtPressThreatsDistinctUrl: state => {
        return state.baseUrl + state.thhlastikaCtPressThreatsUrl + '/getAllActCodes'
    },
    getCtPressThreatsDynamicSearchUrl: state => {
        return state.baseUrl + state.thhlastikaCtPressThreatsUrl + '/search'
    },
    getCtPressThreatsDynamicDownloadUrl: state => {
        return state.baseUrl + state.thhlastikaCtPressThreatsUrl + '/downloadExcel'
    },

    // Thhlastika X Eidh
    getThhlastikaXEidhAddUrl: state => {
        return state.baseUrl + state.thhlastikaXEidhUrl
    },
    getThhlastikaXEidhAddFromExcelUrl: state => {
        return state.baseUrl + state.thhlastikaXEidhUrl + '/addDeigmaThhlastikwnXEidhFromExcel'
    },
    getThhlastikaXEidhSearchUrl: state => {
        return state.baseUrl + state.thhlastikaXEidhUrl + '/getAllByPaging'
    },
    getThhlastikaXEidhByIdUrl: state => {
        return state.baseUrl + state.thhlastikaXEidhUrl + '/'
    },
    getThhlastikaXEidhByDeigmaThhlastikwnIdIs: state => {
        return state.baseUrl + state.thhlastikaXEidhUrl + '/getDeigmaThhlastikwnXEidhByDeigmaThhlastikwnIs/'
    },
    getThhlastikaXEidhDynamicSearchUrl: state => {
        return state.baseUrl + state.thhlastikaXEidhUrl + '/search'
    },
    getThhlastikaXEidhDynamicDownloadUrl: state => {
        return state.baseUrl + state.thhlastikaXEidhUrl + '/downloadExcel'
    },
    getThhlastikaXEidhAutocompletes: state => {
        return state.baseUrl + state.thhlastikaXEidhUrl + '/getAutocompletes'
    },

    // Thhlastika X PressThreats
    getThhlastikaXPressThreatsAddUrl: state => {
        return state.baseUrl + state.thhlastikaXPressThreatsUrl
    },
    getThhlastikaXPressThreatsAddFromExcelUrl: state => {
        return state.baseUrl + state.thhlastikaXPressThreatsUrl + '/addDeigmaThhlastikwnXPressThreatsFromExcel'
    },
    getThhlastikaXPressThreatsSearchUrl: state => {
        return state.baseUrl + state.thhlastikaXPressThreatsUrl + '/getAllByPaging'
    },
    getThhlastikaXPressThreatsByIdUrl: state => {
        return state.baseUrl + state.thhlastikaXPressThreatsUrl + '/'
    },
    getThhlastikaXPressThreatsByDeigmaThhlastikwnIdIs: state => {
        return state.baseUrl + state.thhlastikaXPressThreatsUrl + '/getDeigmaThhlastikwnXPressThreatsByDeigmaThhlastikwnIs/'
    },
    getThhlastikaXPressThreatsDynamicSearchUrl: state => {
        return state.baseUrl + state.thhlastikaXPressThreatsUrl + '/search'
    },
    getThhlastikaXPressThreatsDynamicDownloadUrl: state => {
        return state.baseUrl + state.thhlastikaXPressThreatsUrl + '/downloadExcel'
    },
    getThhlastikaXPressThreatsAutocompletes: state => {
        return state.baseUrl + state.thhlastikaXPressThreatsUrl + '/getAutocompletes'
    },
}

export const mutations = {
    // setSnackbar (state, snackbar) {
    //     state.snackbar = snackbar
    // },
}

export const actions = {
    // setSnackbarSettings ({ commit }, snackbar, snackbarColor, snackbarText) {
        // commit('setSnackbarColor', snackbarColor)
    // },
}
```

my nuxt.config.js

```
const pkg = require('./package')

module.exports = {
  mode: 'universal',

  /*
  ** Headers of the page
  */
  head: {
    htmlAttrs: {
      lang: 'el'
    },
    title: 'Φορέας Διαχείρισης Λίμνης Κερκίνης',
    meta: [
      { charset: 'utf-8' },
      { name: 'viewport', content: 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1' },
      { hid: 'description', name: 'description', content: 'Ο Φορέας Διαχείρισης Λίμνης Κερκίνης είναι υπεύθυνος για την μελέτη, συλλογή, αποθήκευση και ανάλυση πληροφοριών με τη δημιουργία στατιστικών για τη περιοχή της Λίμνης Κερκίνης.' }
    ],
    link: [
      { rel: 'icon', type: 'image/x-icon', href: '/logo.png' },
      { rel: 'stylesheet', href: 'https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500,700|Material+Icons' }
    ]
  },

  /*
  ** Customize the progress-bar color
  */
  loading: { color: '#1B5E20' },

  /*
  ** Global CSS
  */
  css: [
    '~/assets/style/app.styl'
  ],

  /*
  ** Plugins to load before mounting the App
  */
  plugins: [


    '@/plugins/vuetify'
  ],

  /*
  ** Nuxt.js modules
  */
  modules: [


    // Doc: https://github.com/nuxt-community/axios-module#usage

        '@nuxtjs/axios'
  ],
  /*
  ** Axios module configuration
  */
  axios: {

   },

   env: {
    apiBaseUrl:'https://spring-boota.herokuapp.com'
  },
  /*
  ** Build configuration
  */
  build: {
    /*
    ** You can extend webpack config here
    */
    extend(config, ctx) {

    }
  },

}
```

Spring boot view log on Heroku

```
2019-04-25T09:43:00.992627+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:87) ~[kerkinibackend-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
2019-04-25T09:43:00.992628+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:50) ~[kerkinibackend-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
2019-04-25T09:43:00.992631+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:51) ~[kerkinibackend-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
2019-04-25T09:43:00.992632+00:00 app[web.1]: Caused by: java.sql.SQLFeatureNotSupportedException: Method org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection.createClob() is not yet implemented.
2019-04-25T09:43:00.992633+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.postgresql.Driver.notImplemented(Driver.java:683) ~[postgresql-42.2.2.jar!/:42.2.2]
2019-04-25T09:43:00.992634+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection.createClob(PgConnection.java:1252) ~[postgresql-42.2.2.jar!/:42.2.2]
2019-04-25T09:43:00.992636+00:00 app[web.1]:    ... 52 common frames omitted
2019-04-25T09:43:00.992637+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2019-04-25T09:43:01.000940+00:00 app[web.1]: 2019-04-25 09:43:01.000  INFO 4 --- [           main] org.hibernate.type.BasicTypeRegistry     : HHH000270: Type registration [java.util.UUID] overrides previous : org.hibernate.type.UUIDBinaryType@74bf1791
2019-04-25T09:43:03.156892+00:00 app[web.1]: 2019-04-25 09:43:03.156  INFO 4 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2019-04-25T09:43:04.903510+00:00 app[web.1]: 2019-04-25 09:43:04.903  INFO 4 --- [           main] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Initializing ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'
2019-04-25T09:43:04.983028+00:00 app[web.1]: 2019-04-25 09:43:04.982  WARN 4 --- [           main] aWebConfiguration$JpaWebMvcConfiguration : spring.jpa.open-in-view is enabled by default. Therefore, database queries may be performed during view rendering. Explicitly configure spring.jpa.open-in-view to disable this warning
2019-04-25T09:43:05.424035+00:00 app[web.1]: 2019-04-25 09:43:05.423  INFO 4 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 21819 (http) with context path ''
2019-04-25T09:43:05.427954+00:00 app[web.1]: 2019-04-25 09:43:05.427  INFO 4 --- [           main] c.t.k.KerkinibackendApplication          : Started KerkinibackendApplication in 11.091 seconds (JVM running for 12.095)
2019-04-25T09:43:05.824560+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about setting baseURL for axios in nuxt.config?

```
axios: {
baseURL: 'https://spring-boota.herokuapp.com'
}
```

Comment: The baseUrl in index.js should be localhost:8080 ? or i should change it to.The is when i run nuxt on browser doesnt work POST and GET

Comment: Just remove base URL from index-js and your urls. Axios will apply the baseUrl to all request by default with the above mentioned configuration.

Comment: Doesn't work propably can't see spring boot domains when i am running it on heroku !

Comment: 2019-04-27T07:33:49.335424+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=OPTIONS path="/undefinedv1/prwtokola" host=spring-boota.herokuapp.com request_id=0ac8fd48-ef30-4bac-9f7b-4f05ff5cb913 fwd="213.16.231.201" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=180ms status=403 bytes=166 protocol=https